# Publishing Java EE project under Eclipse to WebLogic Server

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, weblogic11g

I have a Java EE project under JDeveloper 11g and I'm now moving to Eclipse.

My Java EE project has a standard structure:
Project C (Utility Project)
Project B (EJB Project)
Project A (web project)

Under JDeveloper, this is what we do to properly publish and use the application:

1. Project C is added as a dependency for both Project B & A (i.e. Project B and A both access/utilize Java classes in Project C)
2. Project A utilizes class and calls to session beans that reside in Project B so Project B is added as a dependency to Project A.

Once these are setup, all what we do is run/debug the application and the integrated WebLogic server is started and the projects above are deployed. There's no EAR/JAR packaging here.

Moving to Eclipse (Neon 2), we did the following:

1. Project A, B & C were moved to become Eclipse-based projects
2. Project C was added to the build path of both Project B and A. This resulted in a clean (0-error) compilation of all 3 projects under Eclipse IDE.
3. Project C was added to the deployment assembly of both Project B and A
4. Project B was added to the deployment assembly of Project A.
5. Using OEPE, a new Weblogic server was added and pointed to WebLogic's base domain (This was tested and the weblogic server can be started and accessed properly)

When attempting to publish the application, it kept failing with the following error:

> weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentException: The module wm-webapp in application _auto_generated_ear_ uses ejb-links but no EJB modules were found for this application.

In order to isolate the problem, I tried to publish Project B (EJB Project) alone. I got a ClassDefNotFound error where the class in question is found in Project C. Not sure if it's related to the first issue but trying to cover the various errors that we got.

I have 2 main questions:

1. Obviously, the main question is what am I doing wrong here?
2. I'm assuming I can still deploy to a WebLogic server using Eclipse without the need to package my projects to EARS, JARs etc... (Just like what we've been doing under JDev). Is that a correct assumption? We want to publish via Eclipse so that we're still able to use the 'debugging' feataure without reverting to options like 'Debugging via Remote Java Application' or via native logging etc...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming I can still deploy to a WebLogic server using Eclipse
>   without the need to package my projects to EARS, JARs etc... (Just
>   like what we've been doing under JDev). Is that a correct assumption?

Wrong.

This is one of the problems with depending too much on an IDE like Eclipse: It allows you to not know what's going on.

Java EE app servers require that you package your app into a WAR (or EAR if you have EJBs).  IntelliJ creates an exploded WAR, so you don't have to package and move a WAR file.  But the layout of the files in the artifact matches the WAR standard exactly.

Comment: Fair enough. However, something doesn't make sense here. If under eclipse, and running on a WebLogic server, the only way to publish is to actually generate and EAR/War files and manually deploy them; then how would you end up debugging your code via the IDE? It just sounds too much of a hassle for an advanced IDE such as Eclipse

Comment: IntelliJ uses the exploded WAR to run locally, but when I deploy it to the Java EE app my CI build tool Jenkins creates a WAR and puts it in the /deployment folder in JBOSS.  Eclipse/WebLogic must be doing something similar.